# Ruby on Rails : Filter with has_many :through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a form in my index.html.erb and i would like to filter the projects with the "eligibles" table. How can I do with has_many :through association ? I wrote a request in my controller but it doesn't work.

Thank you very much for your advice !

**MODEL:
Project_eligible.rb**

```
class ProjectEligible < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :eligible
end
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_eligibles
  has_many :eligibles, through: :project_eligibles

  scope :eligibles, -> (eligibles) { where eligibles: eligibles }
end
```

**eligible.rb**

```
class Eligible < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_eligibles
  has_many :projects, through: :project_eligibles
end
```

**CONTROLLER:
project_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @search = Search.new(search_params)
    @eligibles = Eligible.all

    session[:search] = params[:search] if params[:search].present?
    request = Project

    return @projects = request.page(params[:page]).order("expiration ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2) unless session[:search].present?

    request = request.joins(:eligibles).where(eligibles: session[:search]['eligibles']) if session[:search]['eligibles'].present?
    @projects = request.page(params[:page]).order("expiration ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
end

private

def search_params
    if params[:search].present?
        p = params.require(:search).permit!
        session[:search] = p
    else
        session[:search]
    end
end
```

**VIEW: 
Index.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-inputs" id="form">
    <%= simple_form_for @search, method: :get, url: projects_path do |f| %>
      <div>
          <%= f.input :eligible, :include_blank => "Tous publics", required: false, label: false, collection: @eligibles, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
      <div>
          <%= f.submit 'GO', class: 'btn btn-primary paddind-category btn-from-search' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for or not but after you've defined @projects try @projects= @projects.reject!{ |x| x.project_eligibles.empty? }

Comment: always share the error on SO

Comment: _I'm sorry, after several days, I found the solution_: `request = request.joins(:project_eligibles).where(project_eligibles: {eligible_id: session[:search]['eligible']}) if session[:search]['eligible'].present?` _Just a problem of understanding has_many through association_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
 request = request.joins(:project_eligibles).where(project_eligibles: {eligible_id: session[:search]['eligible']}) if session[:search]['eligible'].present?
```

And not: `request = request.joins(:eligibles).where(eligibles: session[:search]['eligibles']) if session[:search]['eligibles'].present?`